# get number of purchases for managed item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I added some items to my store so people will be able to make in-app purchases.

I want to display the number of purchases for every item in my store and I didn't find a way to do that.

how can I get the number of purchases for a specific managed item in my Google store?

Answer (score 0):

If it is managed product then how can a user purchase that product more than one time. Well I am considering that you are asking if you consume that product and then again purchase that product, for that there is no way to get the number of times you have purchased that product.

Comment: I meant that I want to count how many times a product was purchased by all users. Lets say that every user can purchase item X one time. I want to count the number of users that purchased item X.